# OpenBugs/R categorical variable "yes", "no" as 1,0

Tags: r, openbugs

I have a simple logistical regression like

```
logit(p[i]) <- b0 + b1*x[i]
```

but data for the p[i] is given as "yes", "no". How to encode ("yes"/"no") to (1,0) ?

e.g. smt like this

```
logit(encode(p[i])) <- b0 + b1*x[i]
```

Comment: Hi @NovaTechGuy, an `ifelse` statement will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the old fashion way! I am assuming that p and x are columns of data that I combine in a dataframe named df.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stats) # for glm
df <- as.dataframe(cbind(p,x))
df %>% mutate(p=ifelse(p=="yes",1,0)
logit.model <- glm(p~x, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(logit.model)
```

Comment: I need to build a openBugs model, in R would have been so easy. Thanks